# document getElementById is null when using variable , need to load javascript to find id

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, getelementbyid

I am trying to build html that will interactively use hide or none while building a 99 bottle of beer script showing just the current verse. hides it onclick and brings up the next verse.

Because the page is rendered, the id I am building is null.

How can I get the whole script to run the id can be referenced.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Bottles</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
//declaring global variables

var maxBottleCount =10;
var bottleCount=maxBottleCount;
var bottleDown = bottleCount-1;
var myID = "";
var myIDOld= "";
doBottles(bottleCount,bottleDown);

function doBottles(bottleCount,bottleDown)
{
// 

//document.getElementByID(myID).addEventListener("onclick",redo(myID,myIDOld);
if (bottleCount > 0){
 //alert(bottleCount);
var textBottleCount = bottleCount.toString();
var textBottleDown = bottleDown.toString();
//setting setting id so i can stop program
myIDOld=myID;
myID="\"buildBeer" + textBottleCount + "\"";

//alert(myID);
//myID="\"buildBeer" + textBottleCount + "\"";
//document.getElementById(myId).onclick = redo(myID)
var bottleImages = "<img src=\"_images/beer-bottle-clipart-11.jpg\">";
myHTML = "<p id=" + myID + " on>" + textBottleCount + " bottles " + textBottleDown + " bottles " + "<br />";
var i=1; 
//alert (myHTML);
while (i<= bottleCount){
 //document.write(i);
// alert (bottleCount);
 myHTML = myHTML + bottleImages;
 i++;
}
myHTML+="</p>";
document.write(myHTML);
//alert(bottleCount);
alert(myID);alert(myHTML);
if (bottleCount < maxBottleCount){
 document.getElementById(myID).style.display = 'none';
 alert(myID);
}
//alert(bottleCount);
//alert(maxBottleCount);
bottleCount--;
bottleDown--;
//Using a recursive function to save code (function calls it self until out of bottle.  
 //element1 = document.getElementById(myID);
            
//redo();
redo(myID,myIDOld);

}

// document.write="no More";

}
//myHTML.innerHTML = myHTML;
function redo(myID,myIDOld){
 alert (myID);
 doBottles(--bottleCount,--bottleDown);
 element1 = document.getElementById(myID);
 element1.addEventListener("click", changeHide(myID,myIDOld));
}
function changeHide(aHide,aShow){
 document.getElementById(aShow).style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById(aHide).style.display = 'none';

    }
    

 
function dodo(){}
</script>
<h1>No More Bottles of beer on the wall</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

This is code that show the final result after 10 click on the paragraph

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Bottles</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
//declaring global variables

var maxBottleCount =10;
var bottleCount=maxBottleCount;
var bottleDown = bottleCount-1;
var myID = "";
var myIDOld= "";
doBottles(bottleCount,bottleDown);

function doBottles(bottleCount,bottleDown)
{
// 

//document.getElementByID(myID).addEventListener("onclick",redo(myID,myIDOld);
if (bottleCount > 0){
 //alert(bottleCount);
var textBottleCount = bottleCount.toString();
var textBottleDown = bottleDown.toString();
//setting setting id so i can stop program
myIDOld=myID;
myID="\"buildBeer" + textBottleCount + "\"";

//alert(myID);
//myID="\"buildBeer" + textBottleCount + "\"";
//document.getElementById(myId).onclick = redo(myID)
var bottleImages = "<img src=\"_images/beer-bottle-clipart-11.jpg\">";
myHTML = "<p class=" + myID + " on>" + textBottleCount + " bottles " + textBottleDown + " bottles " + "<br />";
var i=1; 
//alert (myHTML);
while (i<= bottleCount){
 //document.write(i);
// alert (bottleCount);
 myHTML = myHTML + bottleImages;
 i++;
}
document.write(myHTML + "</p>");
//alert(bottleCount);
//alert(maxBottleCount);
/**if (bottleCount < maxBottleCount){
 hideshow(myID);
 alert(myID);
}*/

bottleCount--;
bottleDown--;
//Using a recursive function to save code (function calls it self until out of bottle.  
 //element1 = document.getElementById(myID);
            
//redo();
redo(myID,myIDOld);

}

// document.write="no More";

}
//myHTML.innerHTML = myHTML;
function redo(myID,myIDOld){
 //alert (myID);
 doBottles(--bottleCount,--bottleDown);
 //element1 = document.getElementById(myID);
 //element1.addEventListener("click", changeHide(myID,myIDOld));
}
function changeHide(aHide,aShow){
 hideshow(aHide);
 hideshow(aShow);
    }
    
function hideshow(which){
 alert(document.getElementbyId(which));
if (!document.getElementById)
{return;}
if (which.style.display=="block")
{which.style.display="none";}
else
{which.style.display="block";}
```

}

```
function dodo(){}
</script>
<h1>No More Bottles of beer on the wall</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the error? Where is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Could you describe your problem more specific? I can't quite understand what you can't achieve.

### 1. Watch out for typos.

You have a typo. It's `document.getElementById`, not `document.getElementByID` .

[image: google dev scr]

### 2. Read about other functions

I can see a lot of string operations to get proper IDs. If you have so many `<img />` tags, why don't you just make them like this

```
<img class="myImage" src="smth.jpg" />
<img class="myImage" src="smth.jpg" />
<img class="myImage" src="smth.jpg" />
```

and then load them as such:

```
var images = document.getElementsByClassName("myImage");
```

Doesn't it look better? Then you can just `image[0].src = "stuffs";`

### 3. Use your console

Next time when debugging, try using Google Dev Tools (Ctrl+Shift+J in Google chrome) in order to get more specific information about your error. I'm sure there was something like `undefined is not a method` or something of that ilk, you just didn't look it up.

Comment: The problem is that it displays all the page before the add the event handles. there for the id is nut when the javascript hadles the exception.

Comment: So what is the problem? Does it notes any exceptions? Can u show us this on fiddle or some pastebin?